# Can I make all unix users samba users?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to set up a samba share for the first time.  My guest share works fine, but I cannot seem to log in as any user.  If I enter my unix username and password my mac window just shakes as if an incorrect password was entered.

From what I have read, I thought that because I have `security = user` set in my smb.conf file, anyone with a unix account on my server would also be able to log into samba.  Do I still need to use `smbpasswd` to allow someone access?  Is there an option I can set so that all unix accounts have an associated samba account, with the same password?  I believe `unix password sync = yes` helps with setting something up like that?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that installing `libpam-smbpass` allows this. I am unsure whether the package installation "converts" existing users.

What I did to see this:

1. `sudo apt-get install libpam-passwd`
2. (as my normal user) `passwd <enter appropriate info>`
3. `sudo pdbedit -L`

And now my user is in the list.